# Seleção de texto via teclado

Tags: navegador-de-internet, teclado, acessibilidade

Já parou para imaginar como selecionar um texto de uma parte especifica da sua navegação?

Por exemplo para selecionar dentro de uma caixa de `input` usamos setas de direcionamento assim: <kbd>shit + ⇐</kbd>, <kbd>shit + ⇒</kbd>, <kbd>shit + ⇑</kbd> e <kbd>shit + ⇓</kbd>.
Ou então se usa <kbd>ctrl + a</kbd>, assim selecionando todo o texto.

Mas e para selecionar uma parte especifica para um possível <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd>, dentro da minha navegação via teclado ou <kbd>tab</kbd>?

Alguém sabe como resolver essa acessibilidade?

Comment: No Firefox e no IE11 é só apertar F7 e selecionar qualquer texto com o cursor normalmente. Só que o site é sobre programação, questões de suporte [são fora do escopo](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Nunca parei pra imaginar isso, mas vlw por me informar os atalhos que não conhecia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom acredito que pode variar para cada SO.

No windows você faz o seguinte :

`CTRL+F` e digita a palavra que está buscando

e para navegar você dá um `ESC` a palavra já estará pronta para o `CTRL+C`, se quiser navegar use :`CTRL+LEFT/RIGHT`... Se tiver mais de uma ocorrência, para navegar até a próxima : `CTRL+G`.

Isso no Windows 7...

Mas tem uma solução pelo `HTML` também a questão do atributo `tabindex` que pode tornar a `div`que contém o texto navegável através do `TAB`...

Exemplo :

```html
<div tabindex="1">Primeira</div>
<div tabindex="2">Segunda</div>
```

Vou ver as compatibilidades, pois não sei se todas versões aceitam, mas `HTML5` sim..

Comment: Acabei chegando nessa conclusao tambem, vi que o buscar na pagina funciona como um selecionador.

Comment: Poxa, estou tentando votar UP em seu comentario. Mas com tabindex nao estou conseguindo selecionar a votacao. Tenta votar por tab, veja se consegue.

Comment: Ainda nao consegui selecionar o voto em sua resposta, parece que nao tem interacao por tab esse elemento na pagina.

`<div class="vote">
        <input type="hidden" name="_id_" value="184999">
        <a class="vote-up-off" title="Esta resposta é útil">votar a favor</a>
        <span itemprop="upvoteCount" class="vote-count-post ">0</span>
        <a class="vote-down-off" title="Esta resposta não é útil">votar contra</a>
</div>
`

Comment: É realmente teve ter algo que bloqueia na classe, por que se não me engano a tag `a` pega automático o `tab`... vou dar um aolhada e te falo...